# Query on PXFormula

Tags: erp, acumatica

Just want to ask what could be the problem in my coding below, I want to automatically update the Tax Rate column whenever the user selects an ATC which is Tax ID technically. I successfully created a selector for ATC but it does not update the Tax Rate after selection. Below is my DAC, thanks in advance.

```
#region Atc
public abstract class atc : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}
protected String _Atc;
[PXDBString(15, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "ATC")]
//[PXSelector(typeof(Search<Tax.taxID, Where<Tax.taxType, Equal<CSTaxType.withholding>>>),      
//    new Type[] {typeof(Tax.descr)})]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<Tax.taxID, Where<Tax.taxType, Equal<CSTaxType.withholding>>>))]
public virtual String Atc
{
  get
  {
    return this._Atc;
  }
  set
  {
    this._Atc = value;
  }
}      


#endregion


#region Atcrate
public abstract class atcrate : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}
protected Decimal? _Atcrate;
[PXDBDecimal()]
[PXFormula(typeof(Selector<IISI_ARAdjust_Ext.atc, TaxRev.taxRate>))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "ATC Rate")]
public virtual Decimal? Atcrate
{
    get
    {
      return this._Atcrate;
    }
    set
    {
      this._Atcrate = value;
    }
}    

#endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

Add CommitChanges="True" to the Selector for "Atc" in the Selector like below

```
<px:PXSelector CommitChanges="True" ID="edAtc" runat="server"  AutoRefresh="True" DataField="ATC"/>
```

then update the Tax Rate in A Field Updated event like below:

```
public virtual void YourDAC_Atc_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            YourDAC var = (YourDAC)e.Row;
            if (var == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            TaxRate = Formula to get the tax Rate based on the current Atc        }
```